# How to enforce the selection of at least one term from a custom taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy, and would like to force the user to select at least one term from that taxonomy when creating a post in the WordPress admin back-end. Is this possible?

Comment: I forgot to mention - I'm using a drop-down field to display the taxonomy terms when creating a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is not completely possible. One solution would be to swap out the default UI on /wp-admin/post.php & /wp-admin/post-new.php. You can provide the user with radio buttons or a select box. This will work relatively well, but can not be 100% trusted. There is still the possibility that a user could remove all terms via quick edit in /wp-admin/edit.php.

Comment: Hmm, not so straight-forward. Another idea I had was to use the save_post hook to check if a term had been selected, and if not, I could add a default term from the taxonomy.

Comment: That's actually really easy to do, this snippet is a good place to start: http://wordpress.mfields.org/2010/set-default-terms-for-your-custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress-3-0/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years later, but in case it helps anyone else, I found this plugin:

[Require Post Category](https://wordpress.org/plugins/require-post-category/)

Although it only applies to built in category, it is very easy to modify to suit a custom taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

Again a few years later here's another plugin to enforce taxonomy/category/tags selection

[WP Required Taxonomies – Categories and Tags Mandatory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/required-taxonomies/)

Works with gutenberg too as per plugin description